# Laravel Fullcalendar refresh events from database without reloading the page

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, fullcalendar

I have been programming a booking system for the company where I am an intern, and I have everything working. The only issue is that I have to refresh / reload the whole page to update a change made to an event, I am doing this with this function:
`location.reload(false);`

My calling of the calendar:

```
<div class="panel-body body">
   <p>You can create a reservation by dragging in the calendar.</p>
   <p style="margin-top: -20px;">You can edit it by dragging the reservation. And deleting it by clicking on it.</p>
   <div id='calendar' class="calendar"></div>
</div>
```

I load my events with this function:
`events: {!! $bookings !!},`, where `$bookings` is:

```
$columns = [
        'id AS id',
        'start_time AS start',
        'end_time AS end',
        'description AS description',
        'title AS title',
        'user_id AS user_id',
    ];
    $book = Bookings::where('assetId', $assetId);
    $allBookings = $book->get($columns);
    $bookings = $allBookings->toJson();
```

This is my function to create an event in the calendar (Updated from ADyson's answer):

```
select: function (start, end, jsEvent, view) {
            var title = "{{$assets}}";
            var description = prompt();

            if (title && description) {
                var start_time = moment(start, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
                var end_time = moment(end, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
                var event = {
                    title: title,
                    description: description,
                    start: start_time,
                    end: end_time
                };
                console.log(event);
                $.ajax({
                    headers: {
                        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                    },
                    url: "{{url('book/' . $assetId . '/store')}}", //placeholder URL for test
                    type: "POST",
                    data: event,
                    dataType: "json"
                }).done(function(response) { //successful response from the server
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', event, true); //add the newly created event into fullCalendar
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar("unselect");
                });
            }
        },
```

When I console.log my store data, no data is missing / null:

```
description: "jan" end: "2018-10-15 11:30:00" start: "2018-10-15 10:30:00" title: "Beamer"
```

So to come to the question:
I need a function to refresh / reload the events in the calendar, or the calendar itself.
Huge thanks in advance!

Comment: It has methods to update a single events, or all of them … https://fullcalendar.io/docs/updateEvent, https://fullcalendar.io/docs/updateEvents

Comment: Misorude is right. You can add events to the calendar directly using JavaScript. Check the documentation links, misorude has given you them but tbh they're not hard to find for yourself if you look at the main [documentation page](https://fullcalendar.io/docs#toc) .

Comment: When I add `$('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', event);` to the code it doesn't update the event. But when I manually refresh the page it does. I have tried this already but it didn't work.

Comment: In your code for the `select` function you haven't got any variable called `event`, so it's unclear what you're actually doing with that line of code. Update your question with exactly what you tried.

Comment: P.S. for additional flexibility you could also configure fullCalndar to fetch your events through a separate AJAX request - see the patterns [here](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed) and [here](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function) to see what might suit your situation. You do this instead of loading them statically when the page is created. Then, you can re-load all the events from the server easily without refreshing the page, by calling [this method](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/refetchEvents). There is lots you can learn by simply reading the docs...

Comment: I am rendering my events before the select function, the select function is to create events by dragging over the calendar.

Comment: Not to mention, this kind of question has been asked many times before on StackOverflow, I'm really surprised you didn't find a solution or at least a clue from existing information.

Comment: "I am rendering my events before the select function, the select function is to create events by dragging over the calendar."...??? Your statement doesn't make a lot of sense. You say that the created event isn't added to the calendar when you call `$('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', event);`...so when are you calling this method? Logically you can't call it until you've successfully saved your new event (which as you stated, is generated by the `select` callback) to the server.

Comment: I have searched for solutions for problems like mine, but I found no equal problem. I hope your answer helps, thanks in advance.

Comment: I fetch my events before I call any CRUD function, like select (create). I call `$('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', event);` after the event has been created. But the events still don't refresh until I refresh the page manually.

Comment: @misorude actually I just noticed in order to _create_ an event (which is what is done when using the `select` callback) it should be renderEvent, not updateEvent.

Comment: you can edit your question instead, you shouldn't put code in comments. It's hard to read, and, as you've found, you can't fit it all in. Comments are just for brief discussion / clarification. Thanks. Anyway I have posted an answer below, I don't think updateEvent is the correct thing to be using.

Comment: @Jesse isn't it as simple as `$('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear where you are calling the "updateEvent" method, as you haven't shown it in context within your calendar code. But updateEvent only updates an existing event. To create a new event (which is what you do when you use the `select` callback), you need to call [renderEvent](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/renderEvent). You need to call it after the user has selected an area and you've then saved that information to the server successfully. In other words, it should replace your `location.reload` call.

For that to work you'd also need to define an `event` variable to pass to fullCalendar.

This should work for you:

```
select: function (start, end, jsEvent, view) {
  var title = '{{$assets}}';
  var description = prompt();

  if (title && description) {
    var start_time = start.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
    var end_time = end.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
    var event = {
      title: title,
      description: description,
      start: start_time,
      end: end_time
    };
    console.log("{{$assets}}");

    $.ajax({
      headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
      },
      url: "{{url('book/' . $assetId . '/store')}}",
      type: "POST",
      data: event,
      dataType: "json"
    }).done(function(response) { //successful response from the server
      $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', event, true); //add the newly created event into fullCalendar
      $('#calendar').fullCalendar("unselect"); //clear the selection
    });
  }
},
```

Note that I've changed the event object's structure so that the `start_time` and `end_time` properties are now `start` and `end` respectively, in order to make the same object work with fullCalendar. You would need to change your server code to look for these property names in the incoming data, instead of start_time and end_time. If you can't/won't do that, then you'll have to use a separate object to send data to the server - in the $.ajax() call you'd have to write:

```
data: {
  title: title,
  description: description,
  start_time: start_time,
  end_time: end_time
}
```

instead of `data: event`.

P.S. You'll note I simplified the definitions of the start_time and end_time variables - you don't need to make them into momentJS objects, because they are already momentJS objects when fullCalendar gives them to you.

Comment: I have tried to copy+paste your code but I still have to manually refresh the page to let the event update.

Comment: Ok. That's strange, because it should work. Do you perhaps have any console errors in your browser when you run this?

Comment: I can't load the response data of my store function, which is strange.

Comment: "can't" means what? An error? Some other unexpected behaviour? And why do you need it? You already have all the info you need in order to create the event. Please clarify your problem

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/9a86h74m/5/ for a live demo of my code working. The only thing I changed is to use a dummy URL (because I don't have access to yours) and dummy values for test and description. Select a new area of the calendar, it will make a request to the URL, and when it gets a successful response it will create a new event on the calendar. If that isn't working for your version of the code, I can only assume it's because either a) you don't have values for either "test" or "description" (so the AJAX doesn't run), or b) your AJAX call is failing somehow - you need to debug it.

Comment: When I create a event while trying to capture response data from the store function it says: Failed to load response data, while it normally will show the stored data.

Comment: I'll need more detail than that. Is that a JS error? Or a server error? What HTTP response code do you get from the server? By the way, did you change your server code to match the new start and end field names, as I mentioned in the answer?

Comment: I'm sorry, I feel really stupid. I forgot to change the controller's `$request['start_time']` to `$request[start]`. The code does update now, but still only manually.

Comment: I can't see how that's possible unless you've done something else wrong. Did you visit my demo? You'll maybe need to compare and contrast between your version and mine. Check everything very carefully, and maybe step through your code with the debugger to check what's happening.

Comment: I have, I'll update the question with my current code.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Can I just be certain, you calendar element is definitely "#calendar"? i.e. you have a `<div id="calendar"></div>` with that exact ID somewhere on your page? If the id is something else, you'll have to change the code in my question to match. Other than that, as far as I can see, your problem can only otherwise be caused by the things I mentioned earlier (either missing title or description, or error in the AJAX call). I can't determine these things for you because I can't see your environment. You'll have to use the browser's debugger to investigate.

Comment: The ID is calendar, I have put the calling in my question.

Comment: Ok thanks. Now you need to debug the rest of it. Do you understand how to use the JavaScript debugger in your browser's developer tools? IMHO, Chrome has the best/easiest to use one. Make sure the code being executed is the code you're expecting to execute, and that the values in the variables are the ones you expect. And of course check for errors or warnings in the console.

Comment: I have approved your answer, thanks you very much for helping me. I cannot yet upvote answers since I only have 11 rep haha. I will find out what is stopping the event from being updated. Thank you.

Comment: Thankyou. Good luck. I think you only need 15 rep to upvote. I already upvoted your question so I can't help you with that any further!

Comment: I'll get there eventually haha. Thanks.

Comment: I have been working on this for the past 3 hours, I have made it up to this point where it refreshes. All it takes is a click, doesn't matter where in the page, the event just stays blank until i click. I think clicking somewhere in the page causes eventRender to trigger. Do you know how to re-trigger eventRender with a function or something? I have not found anything online, only with resizing.

Comment: You can tell it to [re-render all the events currently on the calendar](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/rerenderEvents) but you shouldn't have to. It sounds like a very odd situation. It also sounds like a slightly separate issue in a way - you've asked how to do without re-loading the page, and we've covered that, but now it sounds like you have some issue caused by external factors. I think your best bet would be to create a new question with the latest code, and try to make a runnable demo which actually reproduces the issue (e.g. using JSFiddle). If you link the question here, I'll look at it

Answer (score -1):

To refetch the events in a FullCalendar, it is as simple as calling:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
```

See: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/refetchEvents

Although, I would only refetch the events when the response is received from the ajax call so a modified version of your call would look like this:

```
...
$.ajax({
     headers: {
     'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
     },
     url: "{{url('book/' . $assetId . '/store')}}",
     type: "POST",
     data: {
         title: title,
         description: description,
         start_time: start_time,
         end_time: end_time
     },
     dataType: "json",
 }).done((function(response){
     $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
 });
 ...
```

> I even suspect that this is why your calendar did not update because (possibly) the `$('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', event);` doesn't wait for the event to be created before it does the update

Comment: If you take a look at ADyson's answer and reply's you can see I have already tried, but I still need to manually refresh the page to show the updated event

Comment: this won't work because `events` is defined as a static array in the calendar. It would only have any effect if `events` was tied to a separate AJAX request to fetch new data from the server. refetchEvents cannot fetch anything new because it doesn't know where to fetch it from. I already mentioned the possibility of using this approach (separate AJAX call for fetching the events) in the main comment thread, but that's a bigger change to make to the server code as well.

Comment: @Jesse If you are referring to refresh the `calendar` portion of your page, then this `$('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');` should do the job. Otherwise if you refer to the _whole_ page, then I suppose you need to manage it some other way. See the updated answer I gave, do you think the ajax request caused the issues?

Comment: @ADyson your comment is true. Well I suppose going by fetching the events at first by a separate ajax call would be the best since he wants to dynamically change the state of the calendar.

Comment: I agree it's a nicer approach. But for simply adding a single newly created event, using renderEvent should suffice.

Comment: I will try fetching my events via ajax, I have updated the question with my current code.

Comment: I will leave this answer for reference to refetching all events with a separate ajax call since you said you will "try fetching my events via ajax".